# Building Vue app after upgrading to version 5 starts throw "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'"

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-5

After upgrading @vue/cli-service to version ^5.0.4. the build command is not functioning normally as before. after building vue js for production, this was showing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` in the console. After checking the code, The error was coming from

```
const Ee = () => `http://localhost:85/${Se()}`, Se = () => Ce() && we() ? 'api' : 'v1/api',
        Ce = () => 'DEVELOPMENT' === {
          NODE_ENV: 'production',
          VUE_APP_API_URL: 'http://localhost:85/',
          VUE_APP_URL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
          BASE_URL: '/'
        }?.VUE_APP_ENVIRONMENT, we = () => {
          NODE_ENV:'production', VUE_APP_API_URL
        :
          'http://localhost:85/', VUE_APP_URL
        :
          'http://localhost:8080/', BASE_URL
        :
          '/'
        }
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

After Better Indentation and pasting code in visual studio code. I found this

[image]

Notice the red squiggly line on lines no. 17, 18, and 19.
This is happening because javascript is expecting a function body and you are returning an object.

```
const we = () => ({ VUE_APP_API_URL: 'http://localhost:85/' })
```

**Note:** the round bracket before the curly bracket.
`() => ({ ... })` instead of `() => { ... }`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for our answer, But this code is located in the minified file in the dist folder. This is not something I've wrote. It's been generated by the vue-cli itself.

Comment: were you able to rectify the issue? usually, VUE_APP* variables are defined in `.env` files. and then builders replace those in the final build.  
do you know from where these variables are coming? I am pretty sure this is config side issue not build or vue issue

Comment: Yes, they are environment variables, ```VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:85/
VUE_APP_URL=http://localhost:8080/``` They are located inside the .env file.